# Return lat and long values of user's current location to be used in a sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, geolocation

I am using HTML5 geolocation to obtain a users current location & display this on a google map. However I also want to return the lat and long values of this location and pass these values to a SQL datasource query. I want a lat variable and and a long variable to pass through. To get the lat I am simply assigning var jsVar = position.coords.latitude but this is not returning anything. I realise that I should be using hiddenfields to achieve to send the var to the server but am not totally sure how exactly to do it when there is more than one hiddenfield. Any help would be really appreciated. Here is what I have:

**Javascript**

```
function SetHiddenVariable() {

  var jsVar = position.coords.latitude;
    // Set the value of the hidden variable to 
    // the value of the javascript variable
    var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
    document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = "Latitude = " + jsVar;
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
    <body onload="SetHiddenVariable()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   
        <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />   
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJSValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" 
           Text="Click to retrieve Javascript Variable" 
           runat="server" onclick="btnJSValue_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code Behind C#

```
protected void btnJSValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtJSValue.Text = inpHide.Value;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

you could just concatinate the data on the client side (use a comma or some other delimiter that makes sense to you and then just separate on the server side. You would only need to use one variable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html way of doing this which should get you started.  You'll just need to wire your button click event and turn the inputs into server side controls.  Good luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
}

function success(position) {
        document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("long").value = position.coords.longitude;
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   
        Lat: <input id="lat" type="text" />
        Long: <input id="long" type="text" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your advice is very logical. My code looks right but for some reason it's not working. 
    }

    function GetLatLong(position) {

        var userlat = position.coords.latitude;
        
        var hiddenControl = '<%= lat.ClientID %>';
        
        document.getElementById("lat").value = userlat;
    }    <input id="lat" type="hidden" runat="server" />   
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJSValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" 
           Text="Click to retrieve Javascript Variable" 
           runat="server" onclick="btnJSValue_Click"/>